# Syntax error (missing operator) when using InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, oledb, oledbcommand

I have an excel spreadsheet from which I'm reading the data, and trying to copy the second row and insert a duplicate at the end of the table. To do this, I'm trying to execute an OleDbDataAdapter.InsertCommand. Here is what I have for that:

```
da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + tableName + "]", connection);
da.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand();
da.InsertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [" + tableName + "] ([F1], [F2], [F3], [F4], [F5], [F6], [F7], [F8], [F9], [F10], [F11]) SELECT [F1], [F2], [F3], [F4], [F5], [F6], [F7], [F8], [F9], [F10], [11] FROM (SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [F1]) AS RowNumber), * FROM [" + tableName + "]) AS CTE WHERE CTE.RowNumber = 2";
da.InsertCommand.Connection = connection;
da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When it hits the last line, I get an error that says `Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [F1])'.`

How can I rewrite the query so that this error doesn't happen?

Comment: The parentheses enclose the expression and the alias. Should be just the expression.

Comment: You need to remove `)` from `RowNumber)`

Comment: And the matching `(` before `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: @madreflection I tried this suggestion but I still get the same error

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya see above comment

Comment: What's your data source? SQL Server, Access, Excel...? The `OleDb` classes are typically only used for Access or Excel, which probably don't support `ROW_NUMBER`. If you're using SQL Server, use the `Sql` classes, e.g. `SqlCommand`.

Comment: @madreflection I'm getting the data from an Excel sheet. If Excel doesn't support ROW_NUMBER, is there different way to duplicate the second row and add it onto the end of the table?

Comment: @madreflection In the end, I'm trying to insert a row in the 2nd index. My plan was to duplicate the 2nd row and place it at the very end of the table, then update the second row to show the new values that I wanted to insert. If there is a way to simply insert a new row at the nth index, it would be even better.

Comment: You might be better off using something that treats the file as an Excel workbook rather than applying the "database table" abstraction. OLE Automation is one way, obviously, but that has its problems (particularly around installation and licensing). There are libraries that can open an Excel file without Excel installed; try one of those.